# Rails - how do I have posts that are specific for that user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a rails application where I generated some scaffold for a title (string) and body (content) for 'posts'.

This allows me to create, edit and delete a post.

I've just installed devise so now I can have users in the application - the only problem is that no matter what I'm logged in as, the same posts show up.

Is there a way to have specific posts to each user? Would I have to change the post or user model or add a new controller?

If that confused you, another way to put it is that I'd like for each user to create their own 'posts' that other users can't see.

#### Update

Here is the posts_controller

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

# GET /posts
# GET /posts.json
def index
  # @posts = current_user.posts
  @posts = Post.all

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @posts }
  end
end

# GET /posts/1
# GET /posts/1.json
def show
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @post }
  end
end

# GET /posts/new
# GET /posts/new.json
def new
  @post = Post.new

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @post }
  end
end

# GET /posts/1/edit
def edit
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end

# POST /posts
# POST /posts.json
def create
  @post = Post.new(params[:post])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @post.save
      format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render json: @post, status: :created, location: @post }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

# PUT /posts/1
# PUT /posts/1.json
def update
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @post.update_attributes(params[:post])
      format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    else
      format.html { render action: "edit" }
      format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

# DELETE /posts/1
# DELETE /posts/1.json
def destroy
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  @post.destroy

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to posts_url }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end
end
```

And here is the post model

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :name

  belongs_to :user
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Posts **controller** use `@posts = current_user.posts` in the index method.

You will need to have the Post `belongs_to` User / User `has_many` posts relationships set up in the Post and User **models**.

Now your **view** for posts/index can iterate over @posts and they'll just be for that user.

Comment: Should I add that at the beginning or the end?

Comment: please post your controller/model/view but you must have missed something somewhere

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify your view and/or your post controller to show only the post where user_id = current_user. You also have to have a user_id in your post model. If you add your code here someone will be able to help you I guess

Updated :

Add has_many :posts to user model

And then replace in post controller :

```
def index
 @posts = current_user.posts

 respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @posts }
 end
end
```

Also you do have a user_id column in the post model ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add association in users models, as a user can have multilple posts, so you add this in your users model

```
has_many :posts
```

then in index method of your posts controller, you do something like this

```
respond_to :html, :xml, :json

def index
  @posts = current_user.posts    
  respond_with(@post)
end
```

about respond_with, we can specify what resource formats are supported with the class method respond_to, then in controller action we tell controller the resource or resources to be delivered using respond_with

Answer (score -1):

Of course you can set up associations between a user and its posts!

Comment: Downvote. Could you have provided information as to how the asker would have gone about this?